# Camel JAVA DSL - invoking routes from code

Tags: java, apache-camel

Suppose say a camel has two independent routes say for eg.

```
from("/route1").log({body})....<n routes>...to("**bean:someClassABC**");

from("/route2").log({body})....<n routes>...to("bean:someClassXYZ").end();
```

Is it possible to invoke Camel Route2 from this class **SomeClassABC**  via HTTPResponse method httpResponse.sendRedirect("/route2")

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to solve, but if `/route2` is a HTTP consumer, `someClassABC` should use either a HTTP client or use Camel's ProducerTemplate to invoke that route directly. For simplicity reasons I'd would recommend the latter one.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Maybe I would try with a HttpClient or RestTemplate